# Getting an N-N relation in a template

Tags: python, django

I have these models (an owner can have multiple cars, and a car can have multiple owners):

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class CarOwner(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, default = 0, on_delete=Models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, default = 0, on_delete=Models.CASCADE)
```

and I want to create a template that shows a list of cars with their owners, so I did this:

```
def cars(request):
   cars = models.Cars.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'template.html', { "cars": cars })
```

My `template.html` is as simple as

```
{% for car in cars %}
   {{ car.name }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I now refer to all users per car in the `template.html` file?

Comment: Does car owner have any other fields on it? (i.e registration date or similar)

Comment: @Sayse no, this model is only to create the many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CarOwner is the through table of a many-to-many relationship. You should make that explicit:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField('Owner', through='CarOwner')
```

Now you can do:

```
{% for car in cars %}
   {{ car.name }} <br>
   {% for owner in car.owners.all %}
       {{ owner.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is the `CarOwner` class still necessary in this scenario?

Comment: No, not at all - only if you want to record extra data about the relationship.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I inherited this code and it looks like the previous coder didn't know about `ManyToManyField`.